# ScrollsToTop feature is not working in iOS9 properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, statusbar

I have a `UIViewController` having a `UITableView` with large data. I want to implement the feature of scrolltotop on press of the statusbar.

I have a lot of UIView set through my storyboard so I first try to set `scrollsToTop = NO` for all and then set the `scrollsToTop = YES` for the `UITableView` specifically in `viewDidLoad`.

The same settings/configuration works with `iOS8` but not with `iOS9`.

I have applied below code to disable scroll for all subviews in start:

```
- (void)disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf:(UIView *)view {

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollsToTop = NO;
        }
        [self disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf:subview];
    }
}
```

Comment: All you are trying is to scroll tableView to top on tapping status bar correct ???

Comment: Yes SandeepBhandari. Even a tweak to perform the same will be also appreciated.

Comment: I guess there is some scrollview that is not reached by your routine. For example, if there is a scrollview added to table cells, you will have a problem.

Comment: For that only I have added the removal code, which should unset all the other scrolls in start

Comment: @Subso It won't if the views are not in the hierarchy yet. You could modify your code to print scroll views that have `scrollsToTop` set to `YES` and call it later, for example in reaction to a button click. That should give you a better info.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using content offset

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call it on `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Call scroll to top here
}
```

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this started working flawlessly in iOS 10.0

Answer (score 0):

You might have more than one `UIScrollView` in your view hierarchy, and you have to set only the one you want to scroll to top to Yes and the others `scrollsToTop = No;`.